# Hide Node Title if Paragraph Type Exists?

Tags: 8, theming, 9

How do I hide node titles on pages *only* when a specific paragraph type is being used?

For example, the paragraph field is "field_cta" and it has 3 choices of paragraphs "paragraph_a" 'paragraph_b' 'paragraph_c.'

If 'paragraph_c' is added as a paragraph of 'field_cta', I need to hide the title.